# Problem with the differential equation $2u_{xx}-3u_{xy}+u_{yy}+u_x-u_y=1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

Specify the largest domain in which the given Cauchy problem has a single solution, and find this solution
$$2u_{xx}-3u_{xy}+u_{yy}+u_x-u_y=1, \; u\Bigg|_{x=0,y>0}=-2y, \; u_x\Bigg|_{x=0,y>0}=-1$$

Note that a linear hyperbolic equation of second order is given. To
find the domain in which the Cauchy problem has a single solution, we
first find the characteristic equations
$$2y'^2-3y+1=0\Rightarrow y'=\left \{ \frac{1}{2},1 \right \}$$

If $y' = 1/2$ we get $y = x/2 + C_1$, then at $x = 0$, $y = C_1$, and $u =-2y = -2C_1$. Hence our characteristic passes through the point $(0, C_1)$,
and $u = -2C_1$. Given $y' = 1$ we obtain $y = x + C_2$, then at $x = 0$, $y = C_2$, and
$u_x = -1$. Hence, our characteristic passes through point $(0, C_2)$, and $u_x = -1$. Substitute the variables $ξ = x - y$ and $η = x/2 + y$, then
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} & =\frac{\partial \xi}{\partial x} \frac{\partial}{\partial \xi}+\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial x} \frac{\partial}{\partial \eta}=\frac{\partial}{\partial \xi}+\frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial}{\partial \eta} \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial y} & =\frac{\partial \xi}{\partial y} \frac{\partial}{\partial \xi}+\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial y} \frac{\partial}{\partial \eta}=-\frac{\partial}{\partial \xi}+\frac{\partial}{\partial \eta}
\end{aligned}
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
2 u_{x x}-3 u_{x y}+u_{y y}=2 & \left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \xi^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \eta^2}\right) u-3\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \xi^2}-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \eta^2}\right) u+\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \xi^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \eta^2}\right) u \Rightarrow \\
& \Rightarrow u_{\xi \eta}=\frac{1}{2} \Rightarrow u_{\xi}=\frac{1}{2} \eta+f(\xi) \Rightarrow u_{\xi \eta}=\frac{1}{4} \xi \eta+F(\xi)+G(\eta)
\end{aligned}
$$
\begin{gathered}
\frac{1}{4} y-2 y-G(y)=-1 \Rightarrow G(y)=-\frac{7}{4} y+1 \Rightarrow F(-y)=-2 y-\left(-\frac{7}{4} y+1\right)=\frac{1}{4} y-1 \Rightarrow \\
\Rightarrow u_{\xi \eta}=\frac{1}{4} \xi \eta+\frac{1}{4} \xi-1-\frac{7}{4} \eta+1=\frac{1}{4} \xi \eta+\frac{1}{4} \xi-\frac{7}{4} \eta \Rightarrow \\
\Rightarrow u(x, y)=\frac{1}{4}(x-y)\left(\frac{1}{2} x+y\right)+\frac{1}{4}(x-y)-\frac{7}{4}\left(\frac{1}{2} x+y\right)=\frac{x^2}{8}+\frac{x y}{8}-\frac{5 x}{8}-\frac{y^2}{4}-2 y
\end{gathered}

*The problem is that I substitute $x=0$ and don't get $-2y$. I have solved the problem incorrectly. Can you tell me how to solve it correctly?*

Comment: My suggestion is $$u(x,y)\mapsto-x-2 y$$

Comment: General solution: $u(x,y)\mapsto F(x+y)+e^{-\frac{x}{2}} G(x+2 y)+x$

With $F(\xi)\mapsto-2\xi$ and $G(\eta)\mapsto 0$ you will match the initial condition/boundary condition.

Comment: @gpmath How did you get that answer?

Comment: @gpmath Sorry, is there any other way you could show me a breakdown of the assignment? I can't open your link

Comment: Please look here: [Q4668263](https://maple.cloud/app/4817504613171200/MSE+Q4668263?key=444E6D77A08B4E81AD3ADF0EE49C0FA6FD77406640C3403B94AEF227FD200ED7)